# Non-diagonalizable matrix that fits function

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

how do I find matrix 3x3 which is non-diagonalizable and fits this function

$$A^{-1}=A^2+A-I$$

where I is the identity matrix.

I started by multiplying it by $A$ so

$$I=A^3+A^2-A$$

and finally

$$0=A^3+A^2-A-I$$

Now I know that fits it's own characteristic polynomial, which is what my problem is, how do I find a matrix with characteristic polynomial

$$λ^3+λ^2-λ-1=0 ??$$
And also how do I incorporate the fact that $A$ is non-diagonalizable.

Thank you.

Comment: Google "companion matrix" ...

Comment: WOW. Thank you, I never heard of that.

Answer (score 3):

The roots of this polynomial are $-1$ (twice) and $1$ (once). So, take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&1\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$